# Ajax success fanction not showing all messages

Tags: jquery, ajax

The below ajax success function is displaying only my last error4 msg. The responses I am checking are coming ok but the message is not displaying.

```
$.ajax({
    type:...
    url :...
    data:...
success: function (exst_rsp) {
//if email is not register
    if (exst_rsp == "email_no") {
        exstInfo.text("error1");
        exstInfo.addClass("error");
        email_err = true;
    }
    else {
        exstInfo.text("");
        exstInfo.removeClass("error");
        email_err = false;
    }

//if user has already submit a coupon
    if (exst_rsp == "played") {
        couponInfo.text("error2");
        couponInfo.addClass("error");
        email_pl_err = true;
    }
    else {
        couponInfo.text("");
        couponInfo.removeClass("error");
        email_pl_err = false;
    }

//if email & pass don't match
    if (exst_rsp == "email_pass_no") {
        matchInfo.text("error3");
        matchInfo.addClass("error");
        pass_err = true;
    }
    else {
        matchInfo.text("");
        matchInfo.removeClass("error");
        pass_err = false;
    }

//if captcha don't match
    if (exst_rsp == "wrong") {
        capthInfo.text("error4");
        capthInfo.addClass("error");
        captcha_err = true;
    }
    else {
        capthInfo.text("");
        capthInfo.removeClass("error");
        captcha_err = false;
    }

    if (exst_rsp == "ok") {
        exst_rsp_ok = false;
        $('#content').load('f.php');
    }
    else {
        exst_rsp_ok = true;
    }
    if (email_reg_err == true || email_pl_err == true || email_pass_err == true || captcha_err == true || exst_rsp_ok == true) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake was that I was useing the same  IDs to display errors. Code Corrected.

And is working fine!

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your code could use some refactoring and could accomplish what you want with a much cleaner function but to give you a working example you can start here.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q3Zpk/1/

You can change the values in the array to see the html change accordingly.

I put the errors in an array to give you a head start but I would look at using error codes instead of strings and a function that gets that array passed to it and parses the errors accordingly.

Comment: It just might be cleaner and reduce typo errors that sometimes can be hard to find in a lot of code. I believe it's more common practice.

Comment: Ok... I will try... My mistake was that I was usein the same id to display errors. It doesn't show at my post because I accidentaly copy/paste the code that I was going to try after I posted here for help. ty